# I am trying to stop my browser from refreshing when making a Post request to the backend in my handleSubmit function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, backend

I have a form with a handleClick on my submit button. In my handleSubmit function I am making a Post request to the backend and it is sending the data to the backend and updating state. However, it is refreshing the whole page when doing so.

How can I prevent it from refreshing the browser?

I've tried e.preventDefault(); this only forces you to hit the refresh to see it rendered in the browser.

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
 console.log(e);
 const data = this.state.list;
 try {
   const addItem = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/addItem', {
     method: 'POST',
     credentials: 'include',
     body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
   });
 } catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
}


componentDidMount() {
  this.getList().then((list) => {
   this.setState({list: list.data})
  }).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err);
  })
}
render() {
 let data = this.state.list
 let categoryList = Object.keys(data).splice(0, 9).map((item) =>
       <div className='category' key={item}>
         <h1> {item} </h1>
         <div className='itemWraper'>
           {data[item].map((value) =>
             <div key={value} style={{display: 'flex'}}>
               <p className='item'> {value} </p>
               <button className='deleteButton' item={value} id= 
                {this.state._id} onClick={() => this.deleteItem(value, 
                this.state._id, item)}>X</button>
             </div>
           )}
         </div>
       </div>
     )
 let category = Object.keys(data).splice(0, 9).map((item) =>
   <option key={item} value={item}>{item}</option>
 )

 return(
   <div className='background'>
       <h1 className='listName'> {this.props.data.name} </h1>
       <div className='wrapper'>
           <form>
             <input className='addItemInput' type='text' name='name' 
             placeholder='your item..' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <div className="select">
             <select name='category' onChange={this.handleChange}>
               <option> Choose a category </option>
                 {category}
             </select>
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} 
            className='addItemButton'> + </button>
          </form>
       </div>
       <div className='categoryWrapper'>
           {categoryList}
       </div>
   </div>
  )
 }
}
```

No errors. It's working functionally. I would just like it to be more react like

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're using a submit button like 
If this is the case, then clicking on that button refreshes the page.
So, changing type from submit to button may solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I removed the type="submit" but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

e.preventDefault() is gonna be necessary for keeping the page from reloading.

You should add the item to your components state or apps state at the same time as you post it so it still displays.

```
handleSubmit = async (e) => {
 console.log(e);
 const data = this.state.list;
 try {
   const addItem = await fetch('http://localhost:9000/addItem', {
     method: 'POST',
     credentials: 'include',
     body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
   });
   this.setState({list: [...this.state.list, YOUR_NEW_ADDITION_TO_THE_LIST]})
 } catch(err) {
   console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: it does keep the page from reloading but it doesnt render the added item on the browser. I'm forced to hit refresh to see the item on the page. i've tried setting the state inside my handleSubmit funciton but that's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, i just added it in my question above